# How can you add a drop shadow to a pgfplots axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Using the shadows TikZ library, we can add a drop shadow to a rectangle. Is there a way to add the same effect to the boxed axis of a pgfplots picture? Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=white, drop shadow] (0,0) rectangle (5, 5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{1.0\baselineskip}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces this:
[image: picture example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1. Working *inside* the `axis` environment, you can use the native layer system of `pgfplots` together with the `rel axis` coordinate system to add the shadow (requires `clip=false`):

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{pgfplots}
   \usetikzlibrary{shadows}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[set layers,clip=false]
   \addplot {x^2};
   \draw[fill=white, drop shadow,on layer=axis background] 
     (rel axis cs:0,0) rectangle (rel axis cs:1,1);
   \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]
2. Working *outside* the `axis` environment, you can name the axis and then use the name to place the shadow on the background using the tikz `backgrounds` library:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{pgfplots}
   \usetikzlibrary{shadows,backgrounds}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[name=myaxis]
   \addplot {x^2};
   \end{axis}
   \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
   \draw[fill=white, drop shadow] (myaxis.north west) rectangle (myaxis.south east);
   \end{pgfonlayer}
   \end{tikzpicture}

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

As a side note, `pgfplots` internally loads TikZ, so no need to load the latter when you load the former. The `minimal` class is meant to serve to test an installation with something like the classic "Hello world!". I'd suggest you not to use if for anything more complex than that.